# Rails - data displayed only after controller is re-saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am experiencing a weird behavior of my Rails application.

I have downloaded my repo from Github, and initiated a development database.
Now when I create an event (thats the purpose of the app), I get to look at it right after I press 'Create' and the browser goes to, say 'events/1'.

**However** if I navigate to the main page, where all of the events are supposed to be listed, the event is not displayed, until I re-save my controller file (I don't have to make any changes in it). Page reloads do not help.

I should also mention that on my previous machine everything worked fine.

here is a part of my controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @events_future = Event.future_events
  end
```

the scope

```
scope :future_events, order('start_date ASC').where('start_date >= ?', Date.today)
```

again, on the same Mac before I had it reformatted the code worked perfect, so I don't think it is my coding (well, I hope). What could this be? Thanks.

Comment: Defining the scope like this won't work in production mode, since the model will be cached, so the scope will be evaluated on load time and Date.today will be cached, as well, until you restart your application. Wrap the `order(...)` part in a lambda. I guess that's causing problems in your current setup.

Comment: You are right!! Thank you! Don't understand why did it work on my previous versions though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you lawitschka above

Defining the scope like this won't work in production mode, since the model will be cached, so the scope will be evaluated on load time and Date.today will be cached, as well, until you restart your application. Wrap the order(...) part in a lambda. I guess that's causing problems in your current setup.